# Realtime database: how to add data from one reference to another reference?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How add this `-N8O6lC8cGgMfLE_8BIR` data from the reference `Colis Futur` to reference `Colis Requetes`

[image]

Here's what should happen. just below

[image]

Comment: I want to add data from `Colis Futur` to `Colis requetes`

Comment: so are you submiting tha data via a form ?

Comment: I detailed in picture, you can watch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a RTDB node from one parent node to the another one, you need to first [read it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) from the source parent node and then [write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write) the node (it's value + key) under the parent target node.

How to do that depends on your exact techno/functional requirements. You could do that from your front end, if for example you app is a "Colis" management app or you could do that in the back-end with a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), for example if you want to denormalize your data according to the NoSQL "philosophy".